# Alternate channels in UWP PWA

Tags: javascript, uwp, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I'm trying to convert my PWA into a UWP with support for background push notifications, and I wanted to use VAPID notifications ([alternate channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/alternate-channel-vapid-webpush)), however there seems to be no JS API for this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out simply that the `@types/winrt-uwp` package on npm isn't updated with the new APIs yet. I could just use something like this to get the channel:

```js
const pnm: any = Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager;
const dpnm = pnm.getDefault();
const notifPromise: any = dpnm.createRawPushNotificationChannelWithAlternateKeyForApplicationAsync(buffer, 'notif');
notifPromise.then(subscription => {
    console.log(subscription);
}
```